# How to move photo path from database to image editor in c#?

Tags: c#, sql, entity-framework, c#-4.0, devexpress

On the Web Desktop App

I print the personnel information in my database into the datagrid. I can bring the required fields dynamically with focusedrowchange. As I bring the information, I want to dynamically add the photo kept as a file path in the database to pictureEdit. Is this possible?

This is how I keep the photo path.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/j0nts.png)

I tried to give a direct path to that part in the table using entities in the code section, but I could not get any results.

Comment: What is web desktop app? What kind of project it is Asp.net core or Windows Form?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: Your question is hard to understand. What's a _"Web Desktop App"_. You say you keep a photo in the database using a path. But, a path in a database isn't much good at keeping an image. It's just a string referencing a location on a file system somewhere; it's not an image. Please add a better explanation and the code you have to hour question